Field profiles using Transfer Matrix Method
I am using the Transfer Matrix Method to compute optical properties such as reflectivity, transmittance as well as to obtain guided modes for multilayer structures. Following the formalist presented in Chapter 5 of Pochi Yeh's book, $\textit{Optical waves in layered media}$, I have written a Python code for computing all these quantities.
Configuration: thin film
Let us focus on the simple configuration of a thin film. For this case, we have three regions: the cover, the guiding film and the substrate, whose refractives indices are $n_{c}$, $n_{f}$ and $n_{s}$, respectively. For the guided modes, we need to find those values of the effective refractive ($n_{eff}$) index which minimizes the absolute value of the M matrix element M22. Hence, I define an array neff which varies from $n_{s}$ to $n_{f}$.
The above-mentioned code is split into three parts: the functions, the constants and the run files. Below, I show each of them.
functions.py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def layers(NL,nc,nf,ns):
    '''
    Creates the multilayer structure.

    Parameters:
    - NL: number of layers considered
    - nc: refractive index of the cover medium;
    - nf: refractive index of the film medium;
    - ns: refractive index of the substrate.

    Returns: the refractive index arrays n_V.
    
    '''
    n_V = np.zeros(NL)
    n_V[0] = nc
    n_V[1] = nf
    n_V[-1] = ns

    return n_V

def result(NP, NL, n_v, d, c, lamb, neff, type, tolerance=5e-4):
    '''
    Computes the transfer matrix M and its inverse for both TE and TM polarisations.

    Parameters:
    - NP: number of discretisation points for quantities such as wavelength and effective refractive index;
    - NL: number of layers;
    - n_v: array of the refractive indices in each layer;
    - d: thickness of the guiding layer;
    - c: speed of light;
    - lamb: wavelength array;
    - neff: effective refractive index array;
    - type: chooses between TE or TM polarisation;

    Returns: 
    - M: the transfer matrix;
    - Minv: the inverse of the transfer matrix;
    - m22: the array with the values of the element m22 of M;
    - kx_values: the wave vectors in each layer; 
    - selected_kx: the wave vectors corresponding to the effective refractive index which minimizes m22;
    - nmin: the values of neff which minimizes m22.
    
    '''
    lambda_values = np.full(NP, lamb)
    w = np.zeros(NP)
    m22 = np.zeros(NP)
    kx_values = []
    an = np.zeros((NP, NL), dtype=complex)  
    bn = np.zeros((NP, NL), dtype=complex)  
    min_indices = []

    for i in range(NP):
        w[i] = (2 * np.pi * c) / lambda_values[i]
        ki = n_v * (w[i] / c)
        kz = neff[i] * ki[0]
        kx = np.lib.scimath.sqrt(ki**2 - kz**2)
        kx_values.append(kx)  

        core_result = np.eye(2)
        core_result_inv = np.eye(2)

        layer_core = np.eye(2)

        # Initialize dynamical matrices of the first and the outermost layers for different polarisations
        if type == 'e':
            D0 = np.array([[1, 1], [(c * kx[0]) / w[i], -(c * kx[0]) / w[i]]])
            DS = np.array([[1, 1], [(c * kx[-1]) / w[i], -(c * kx[-1]) / w[i]]])
        elif type == 'm':
            D0 = np.array([[(c * kx[0]) / (w[i] * n_v[0]), (c * kx[0]) / (w[i] * n_v[0])], [n_v[0], -n_v[0]]])
            DS = np.array([[(c * kx[-1]) / (w[i] * n_v[-1]), (c * kx[-1]) / (w[i] * n_v[-1])], [n_v[-1], -n_v[-1]]])

        # Compute the core of the transfer matrix
        for l in range(NL-2, 0, -1):
            if type == 'e':
                DL = np.array([[1, 1], [(c * kx[l]) / w[i], -(c * kx[l]) / w[i]]])
            elif type == 'm':
                DL = np.array([[(c * kx[l]) / (w[i] * n_v[l]), (c * kx[l]) / (w[i] * n_v[l])], [n_v[l], -n_v[l]]])

            PL = np.array([[np.exp(1j * kx[l] * d), 0], [0, np.exp(-1j * kx[l] * d)]])
            core_result = core_result @ DL @ np.linalg.inv(PL) @ np.linalg.inv(DL)
            core_result_inv = core_result_inv @ DL @ PL @ np.linalg.inv(DL)

        # Compute overall transfer matrix
        Minv = np.linalg.inv(DS) @ core_result @ D0
        M = np.linalg.inv(D0) @ core_result_inv @ DS

        # Extract coefficients from the transfer matrix
        an[i, 0] = 1.0  # Assuming only transmitted wave in the first layer
        bn[i, 0] = 0.0  # Assuming no backward wave in the first layer

        # Initialize forward and backward wave amplitudes for the first layer
        v1 = np.zeros(NL, dtype=complex)
        v2 = np.zeros(NL, dtype=complex)
        v1[0] = an[i, 0]
        v2[0] = bn[i, 0]

        # Propagate the coefficients through each layer
        for l in range(1, NL):
            if type == 'e':
                D0 = np.array([[1, 1], [(c * kx[0]) / w[i], -(c * kx[0]) / w[i]]])
                DL = np.array([[1, 1], [(c * kx[l-1]) / w[i], -(c * kx[l-1]) / w[i]]])
            elif type == 'm':
                D0 = np.array([[(c * kx[0]) / (w[i] * n_v[0]), (c * kx[0]) / (w[i] * n_v[0])], [n_v[0], -n_v[0]]])
                DL = np.array([[(c * kx[l-1]) / (w[i] * n_v[l-1]), (c * kx[l-1]) / (w[i] * n_v[l-1])], [n_v[l-1], -n_v[l-1]]])

            PL = np.array([[np.exp(1j * kx[l-1] * d), 0], [0, np.exp(-1j * kx[l-1] * d)]])
            M_layer = np.linalg.inv(D0) @ DL @ PL @ np.linalg.inv(DL)

            # Solve for new coefficients
            vw = np.linalg.solve(M_layer, [v1[l-1], v2[l-1]])
            v1[l] = vw[0]
            v2[l] = vw[1]

            # Update coefficients arrays
            an[i, l] = v1[l]
            bn[i, l] = v2[l]

        m22[i] = np.abs(M[1, 1])

    for i in range(1, NP - 1):
        if m22[i] < m22[i - 1] and m22[i] < m22[i + 1] and np.abs(m22[i]) < tolerance:
            min_indices.append(i)

    kx_values = np.array(kx_values)  # Convert list to array
    nmin = neff[min_indices]

    # Select coefficients corresponding to nmin
    sel_an = an[min_indices]
    sel_bn = bn[min_indices]
    sel_kx = kx_values[min_indices]

    return M, Minv, m22, kx_values, sel_kx, sel_an, sel_bn, nmin

constants.py
import numpy as np

c = 3.0e8 # speed of light
nf = 3.48 # refractive index of the guiding film
ns = 1.444 # refractive index of the substrate
nc = 1.00 # refractive index of the cover layer
NL = 3 # number of layers of a thin film

lamb = 1550e-9 # working wavelength
d = 1000e-9 # thickness of the guiding film layer
NP = 200000 # number of discretisation points
a0 = 1
b0 = 0

neff = np.linspace(ns+1e-12, nf-1e-12, NP) 


te = 'e' # selects TE polarisation
tm = 'm' #selects TM polarisation

run.py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import constants_v1 as ct
import functions_v1 as ft
import plots_v1 as pt

# Refractive index array
nv = ft.layers(ct.NL, ct.nc, ct.nf, ct.ns)

# Transfer matrix M, |M[1,1]| and its zeros
Mm, Mmi, m22m, kxm, kxem, anm, bnm, mn_min = ft.result(ct.NP, ct.NL, nv, ct.d, ct.c, ct.lamb, ct.neff, ct.tm)
Me, Mei, m22e, kxe, kxee, ane, bne, en_min = ft.result(ct.NP, ct.NL, nv, ct.d, ct.c, ct.lamb, ct.neff, ct.te)

# Plot of the absolute value of M22
pt.m22(ct.neff,m22e)

# Storing the wave vector for TM polarisation
kxe0 = kxee[-1, 0]  # Accessing the first column
kxe1 = kxee[-1, 1]  # Accessing the second column
kxe2 = kxee[-1, 2]  # Accessing the third column

# creating x arrays
xlower = np.linspace(-2 * ct.d, -1 * ct.d, 100)
xmiddle = np.linspace(-1 * ct.d, 0, 100)
xupper = np.linspace(0, 1 * ct.d, 100)

# Define the function for the electric field
def cover(al, bl, kx, x):
    return al * np.exp(-1j * kx * (x - 0 * ct.d)) + bl * np.exp(1j * kx * (x - 0 * ct.d))

def film(al, bl, kx, x):
    return al * np.exp(-1j * kx * (x - ct.d)) + bl * np.exp(1j * kx * (x - ct.d))

def sub(al, bl, kx, x):
    return al * np.exp(-1j * kx * (x - ct.d)) + bl * np.exp(1j * kx * (x - ct.d))

# Calculate the electric field in each region
inc = cover(ane[0, 0], bne[0, 0], kxe0, xlower)
guiding = film(ane[0, 1], bne[0, 1], kxe1, xmiddle)
substrate = sub(ane[0, 2], bne[0, 2], kxe2, xupper)

# Concatenate the positions and electric fields
x = np.concatenate((xlower,xmiddle,xupper))
E = np.concatenate((inc,guiding,substrate))

# Plot the results
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()


E2 = np.abs(E)**2
dE_dx = np.gradient(E, x)

ax1.plot(x, E2, label=r"$\left|E\right|^2$")
ax1.axvline(x=xlower.max(), color='k', linestyle='--')
ax1.axvline(x=xupper.min(), color='k', linestyle='--')
ax1.set_xlim(left=xlower.min(), right=xupper.max())
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$x \left(\mu m\right)$',fontsize=20)
ax1.set_ylabel(r"$\left|E\right|^2$",fontsize=20)
ax1.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci', scilimits=(0,0),useMathText=True)
ax1.xaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(18) 
ax1.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=18)
ax1.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=18)
# ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.legend()
# Plot the derivative
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, np.abs(dE_dx) ** 2, color='r', label=r"$\left|\frac{dE}{dx}\right|$")
ax2.set_ylabel(r"$\left|\frac{dE}{dx}\right|$", color='r',fontsize=20)
ax2.legend(loc='upper right')
ax2.ticklabel_format(axis='x', style='sci', scilimits=(0,0),useMathText=True)
ax2.xaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(18) 
ax2.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci', scilimits=(0,0),useMathText=True)
ax2.xaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(18) 
ax2.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=18)
ax2.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=18)
# ax2.set_yscale('log')
plt.title("Electric Field and Its Derivative")
plt.savefig("electric_field_and_derivative.png", dpi=600)
plt.show()


Problem: how to correctly plot the field configurations
Until the point I obtain the guided modes, everything is correct. The problem comes when I have to plot the electric field configurations associated to each of these guided modes. The general expression for the electric field in the lth layer is given by
$$E_{l}\left(x\right) = a_{l}e^{-i k_{xl} \left(x-x_{l}\right)} + b_{l}e^{i k_{xl} \left(x-x_{l}\right)}$$
where $x_{l}$ is the position of the lth layer. For some reason, the plots I obtain for both the electric field and its derivative display a huge discontinuity as can be seen in the figure below for the lowest order mode. I uploaded the full plot and also the plot with the x values restricted to the cover and film regions, so the arise of the discontinuity is more visible.
I do not know if the problem is in how I am computing the coefficients $a_{l}$ and $b_{l}$ in each layer, or in how I am writing the electric field function, more especifically, if I am correctly writing the exponential dependence with the difference $x-x_{l}$. Any help or comments are heavily appreciated.


